# Get element inside "block" relative of user click without IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but here is my idea:

I have multiple blocks in my page, all of them are built the same and they have the same classes. Only the content in the blocks is different.

I can't / don't want to assign IDs because these blocks get generated by the backend and it's just not suitable to give each an individual ID.

I want to get relative (in the HTML) to where the user clicks the button another element near the button and store that in a variable.

So if my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My first Element 1</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My second Element 2</h3>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <p>Some other tex</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the h3 in a variable, but only in the scope of the block.

So when the user clicks `Button 2` the variable would be `My second Element 2` but when the user clicks `Button 1` the variable would be `My first Element 1`

I think you get the point.

Is that possible to do without IDs? I assume for JS both blocks look the same. Is there any way to stay in the scope of where the user clicks?

When I select the button with `querySelectorAll` and loop through the output then I get multiple results for my `h3` (so a result for any button on the page).

This is an example with a single block with an ID to show how my other code would work.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myScript);

function myScript() {
let result = document.getElementById("button").parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML.trim();
    console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>My first Element 1</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button id="button" class="classButton">Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only part missing is to only select the button that get's actually clicked and get relative to that the `h3`, and only a single `h3` inside the block and not every `h3` on the page.

This is my simplified code of the actual thing without IDs and multiple blocks:

```js
let result;
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".classButton");
button.forEach(click => {
  click.addEventListener("click", myScript);
})


function myScript() {
  button.forEach(i => {
    result = i.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML.trim();
  })

  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My first Element 1</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My second Element 2</h3>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <p>Some other tex</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I either only get the last element or if I put the console.log inside the forEach both.

Any way of doing that?

Thanks!

I know the way of getting the content of the h3 might not be the best way, but that's another problem I can work on as soon as the other part works.

Comment: you can use `window.event.target` from any scope (inside your click event handler for example) to have the element that fired the event.

Comment: I believe you are looking for something similar to event-delegation pattern in javascript

Comment: Why would you loop over _all_ the buttons inside your click handler, that does not make sense. `this` gets you access to the clicked button element inside your event handler - so go up three levels to the outermost `div`, and then select the `h3` in there using `querySelector`, called _on_ that div element.

Comment: @CBroe well, I though I have to loop through it because I get a `NodeList` with multiple elements when I use `querySelectorAll`. I try that, thanks

Comment: You have to loop to add the event handlers to each individual button. But that does not mean, that at the point where you are actually _handling_ the click on an individual button then, you need to loop over all buttons _again_.

Comment: yes the key was as stated since the beginning, having the less handlers as possible and determine which is the element firing the event using `event.target`. You have a reference to event if you accept an argument in your handler (that will be passed by default when the event is fired and caught) or just addressing `window.event.target` from any scope. Using `this` is also an option but obfuscates the semantics ... anyway it works as long as you don't need to craft more complicated handlers ... `this` is a complex topic and one of the most dangerous traps in js

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a function to handle an event inside a loop then you have access to event and element both so you don't have to loop again

```js
let result;
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".classButton");
button.forEach(click => {
  click.addEventListener("click", getH1);
})


function getH1(e){
  let textValue = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerText
  console.log(textValue)
}
```

```html
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My first Element 1</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My second Element 2</h3>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <p>Some other tex</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My second Element 3</h3>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <p>Some other tex</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My second Element 4</h3>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <p>Some other tex</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe's comment I got this solution:

```js
let result;
let buttonEvent = document.querySelectorAll(".classButton");
let button = document.querySelector(".classButton");
buttonEvent.forEach(click => {
  click.addEventListener("click", myScript);
})


function myScript() {
  result = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerHTML.trim()
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My first Element 1</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="this-is-a-block">
  <h3>My second Element 2</h3>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <p>Some other tex</p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="classButton">Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the 100% best way, but it's working.